# Redirecting autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [awesomplete autocomplete plugin](http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/#events) and I need redirectin my item which I selected  when you clicked any result for example I wrote a Javascript and after I clicked it than it must redirect any page that I want.I see [events](http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/#events) but I've no idea how to use it

My structure

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

```css
.awesomplete > ul {
 border-radius: .3em;
 margin: .2em 0 0;
 background: hsla(0,0%,100%,.9);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, hsla(0,0%,100%,.8));
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 box-shadow: .05em .2em .6em rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 text-shadow: none;
}

@supports (transform: scale(0)) {
 .awesomplete > ul {
  transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.4,.2,.5,1.4);
  transform-origin: 1.43em -.43em;
 }
 
 .awesomplete > ul[hidden],
 .awesomplete > ul:empty {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  display: block;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
 }
}

 /* Pointer */
 .awesomplete > ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -.43em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  padding: .4em;
  background: white;
  border: inherit;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
 }

 .awesomplete > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  padding: .2em .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .awesomplete > ul > li:hover {
  background: hsl(200, 40%, 80%);
  color: black;
 }
 
 .awesomplete > ul > li[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: hsl(205, 40%, 40%);
  color: white;
 }
 
  .awesomplete mark {
   background: hsl(65, 100%, 50%);
  }
  
  .awesomplete li:hover mark {
   background: hsl(68, 100%, 41%);
  }
  
  .awesomplete li[aria-selected="true"] mark {
   background: hsl(86, 100%, 21%);
   color: inherit;
  }
```

```html
<input class="awesomplete dropdown-input" list="mylist" id="my-input" />
<datalist id="mylist">
 <option data-link="http://www.google.com">Ada</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.yahoo.com">Java</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.bing.com">JavaScript</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.yandex.com">Brainfuck</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.php.net">LOLCODE</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.asp.net">Node.js</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.microsoft.net">Ruby on Rails</option>
</datalist>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native support to get the attribute of the chosen item.

To bind events, use the `on` function on the chosen selector.

In order to get the `data-link` attribute, you need to get the `datalist` and find the `option` with the text value.

Awesomplete is firing the event twice - once on the input field, and once on the containing div. I am listening for the event on the div by checking if its sibling is the `datalist`. Once I have that, I find the required `option` by using the `:contains` selector, passing in the input field value.

I have to wrap it in a `setTimeout` function as, at that point, Awesomplete has not yet populated the value attribute of the input field.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.awesomplete').on('awesomplete-select', function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $sibling = $this.next();
    if($sibling.attr('id') == 'mylist') {
      setTimeout(function(){
        var val = $this.find('input').val();
        var dataLink = $sibling.find('option:contains("' + val + '")').data('link');
        console.log(dataLink);
        //location.href = dataLink;
      }, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.awesomplete > ul {
 border-radius: .3em;
 margin: .2em 0 0;
 background: hsla(0,0%,100%,.9);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, hsla(0,0%,100%,.8));
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 box-shadow: .05em .2em .6em rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 text-shadow: none;
}

@supports (transform: scale(0)) {
 .awesomplete > ul {
  transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.4,.2,.5,1.4);
  transform-origin: 1.43em -.43em;
 }
 
 .awesomplete > ul[hidden],
 .awesomplete > ul:empty {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  display: block;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
 }
}

 /* Pointer */
 .awesomplete > ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -.43em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  padding: .4em;
  background: white;
  border: inherit;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
 }

 .awesomplete > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  padding: .2em .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .awesomplete > ul > li:hover {
  background: hsl(200, 40%, 80%);
  color: black;
 }
 
 .awesomplete > ul > li[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: hsl(205, 40%, 40%);
  color: white;
 }
 
  .awesomplete mark {
   background: hsl(65, 100%, 50%);
  }
  
  .awesomplete li:hover mark {
   background: hsl(68, 100%, 41%);
  }
  
  .awesomplete li[aria-selected="true"] mark {
   background: hsl(86, 100%, 21%);
   color: inherit;
  }
```

```html
<input class="awesomplete dropdown-input" list="mylist" id="my-input" />
<datalist id="mylist">
 <option data-link="http://www.google.com">Ada</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.yahoo.com">Java</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.bing.com">JavaScript</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.yandex.com">Brainfuck</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.php.net">LOLCODE</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.asp.net">Node.js</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.microsoft.net">Ruby on Rails</option>
</datalist>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **awesomplete-selectcomplete** like this

```js
document.getElementById('my-input').addEventListener('awesomplete-selectcomplete',function(){
  alert(this.value); 
  //TODO HERE
});
```

```css
.awesomplete > ul {
 border-radius: .3em;
 margin: .2em 0 0;
 background: hsla(0,0%,100%,.9);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, hsla(0,0%,100%,.8));
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 box-shadow: .05em .2em .6em rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 text-shadow: none;
}

@supports (transform: scale(0)) {
 .awesomplete > ul {
  transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.4,.2,.5,1.4);
  transform-origin: 1.43em -.43em;
 }
 
 .awesomplete > ul[hidden],
 .awesomplete > ul:empty {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  display: block;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
 }
}

 /* Pointer */
 .awesomplete > ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -.43em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  padding: .4em;
  background: white;
  border: inherit;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
 }

 .awesomplete > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  padding: .2em .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .awesomplete > ul > li:hover {
  background: hsl(200, 40%, 80%);
  color: black;
 }
 
 .awesomplete > ul > li[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: hsl(205, 40%, 40%);
  color: white;
 }
 
  .awesomplete mark {
   background: hsl(65, 100%, 50%);
  }
  
  .awesomplete li:hover mark {
   background: hsl(68, 100%, 41%);
  }
  
  .awesomplete li[aria-selected="true"] mark {
   background: hsl(86, 100%, 21%);
   color: inherit;
  }
```

```html
<input class="awesomplete dropdown-input" list="mylist" id="my-input" />
<datalist id="mylist">
 <option data-link="http://www.google.com">Ada</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.yahoo.com">Java</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.bing.com">JavaScript</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.yandex.com">Brainfuck</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.php.net">LOLCODE</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.asp.net">Node.js</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.microsoft.net">Ruby on Rails</option>
</datalist>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi it's great to understand thank you so much and can we do this with jquery ? `on` instead of `addEventListener` ?

Comment: yes you can do it via jquery also its an listener to bind use an event params inside callback to get the selected item